# finding modulus of huge numbers in java

Tags: java

```
      for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)
        {
            y=y+(a[i]*(int)Math.pow(j,i));
        }
        int r=y/786433;
        s[k]=y-(r*786433);
        k++;
```

Now in this code the `j` value can be `786432`. So when I try to get modulus of a number say `(1+2*(786432)^2+3*(786432)^3)%786433` then I get `-521562` which is not correct I was using modulus operator before too but I got the same answer even with this approach I am getting the same answer. In this approach the modulus of the number is stored in array `s[k]`. Can anyone help?

Comment: 786432 cubed isn't even that big. By the way you can use modular exponentiation to avoid ever having a big number.

Comment: as a sidenode, that´s the remainder operator, and not the modulo operator. The remainder can return negative values if one value is negativ, wheras the mathematical modulo operator can´t do that. If you´d like to have the mathematical modulo use `Math#floorMod`

Comment: @harold but it is too big to store in an `int`.

Comment: @Jesper well fits in a `long`, so even with explicit calculation no bigints are required

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) you are using a double types. Then you convert it back to an int. Rounding can happen and also truncating if values are too big.

To solve this problem You need to use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers

In particular the method [mod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod(java.math.BigInteger)):

> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this mod m). This method differs from remainder in that it always returns a non-negative BigInteger.

Comment: thanks @davideLorenzoMarino the type casting was not required.Its giving positive answer as 2